# Migrate a Kubernetes application to GCP from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, migration

I want to know a brief explanation or an example of how to migrate a `Kubernetes` application to `GCP` from `AWS`.

What services are implicated like `EKS` or `EC2` and `GKE` or `Compute Engine`.

I'm very new to migration, I don't know too much about `AWS` and I recently started using `GCP`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It depends.

## At first, `AWS` -> `GCP` resources mapping:

At first, you'll want to know the mapping between `AWS` and `GCP` resources.
There are several articles:

- [Cloud Services Mapping For AWS, Azure, GCP ,OCI, IBM and Alibaba provider – Technology Geek](https://osamaoracle.com/2020/06/19/services-mapping-aws-azure-gcp-oc-ibm-and-alibab-cloud/)
- [Cloud Terminology Glossary for AWS, Azure, and GCP | Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/blog/cloud-terminology-glossary):
- [Cloud Services Terminology Guide: Comparing AWS vs Azure vs Google | CloudHealth by VMware](https://www.cloudhealthtech.com/blog/cloud-comparison-guide-glossary-aws-azure-gcp)

## Migrate `AWS EKS` to `GCP GKE`: the hard way

If your cluster is deployed with **managed kubernetes** service:

- from `Elastic Kubernetes Service` (`EKS`)
- to `Google Kubernetes Engine` (`GKE`)

Then it would be hard to migrate. Just due to complexity of `kubernetes` architecture and differences in the approaches of manage cluster in `AWS` vs GCP`

## Migrate VMs and cluster deployed using your own `k8s` manifest.

If your `kubernetes` cluster is deployed on cloud virtual machines with `k8s` or `helm` manifests, then it would be easier.

And there are two ways:

- Either migrate `VM`s using `GCP` `Migrate Connector` (as @vicente-ayala said in his answer)
- Or import your infrastructure to the `terraform` manifest, change resources definitions step-by-step, and then apply this updated manifest to `GCP`

### Migrating with `Migrate Connector`

You can found the latest migration manual on migrating VM's here:

#### Prerequisites

As per [`GCP` manual](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/5.0/how-to/migrating-vms),

> Before you can migrate a source VM to Google Cloud, you must configure the migration environment on your on-premises data center and on Google Cloud. See:
>
> - [Enabling Migrate for Compute Engine services](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/5.0/how-to/enable-services)
> - [Installing the Migrate Connector](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/5.0/how-to/migrate-connector)

### Migrating

[How-to Guides  |  Migrate for Compute Engine  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/5.0/how-to)

- [Migrating individual VMs](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/5.0/how-to/migrating-vms)
- [Migrating VM groups](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/5.0/how-to/migrating-vm-groups)

## Migrating using `Terraform` and `Terraformer`

There is a great tool for reverse Terraform [GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer. Infrastructure to Code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer)

A CLI tool that generates `tf`/`json` and `tfstate` files based on existing infrastructure (reverse Terraform).

And you can import your infrastructure into `terraform` manifest:

```
 terraformer import aws --resources=vpc,subnet --connect=true --regions=eu-west-1 --profile=prod
```

You'll get the `terraform` manifest declared with [`aws provider`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest)

And you may try to replace every `AWS` resource to the appropriate `GCP` resource. There is official `terraform GCP` provider: [hashicorp/google](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest). Unfortunately, there isn't mapping for `terraform` resources of both cloud providers. But, again, you may some of these mapping lists:

- [Cloud Services Mapping For AWS, Azure, GCP ,OCI, IBM and Alibaba provider – Technology Geek](https://osamaoracle.com/2020/06/19/services-mapping-aws-azure-gcp-oc-ibm-and-alibab-cloud/)
- [Cloud Terminology Glossary for AWS, Azure, and GCP | Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/blog/cloud-terminology-glossary):
- [Cloud Services Terminology Guide: Comparing AWS vs Azure vs Google | CloudHealth by VMware](https://www.cloudhealthtech.com/blog/cloud-comparison-guide-glossary-aws-azure-gcp)

And then apply the new `GCP` manifest:

```
terraform init
terraform plan
terraform apply
```

## Additional resources on `AWS` <-> `GCP`

- [GCP to AWS Migration: Why and How to Make the Move](https://insights.daffodilsw.com/blog/gcp-to-aws-migration-why-and-how-to-make-the-move)
- [GCP | Google Cloud Migrate for Compute Engine | AWS to GCP Migration using Velostrata - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCQx-neI5UY)
- [Managing a Large and Complex GCP Migration (Cloud Next '19) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdqQEcEUwRE)
- [Lessons Learned Migrating from GCP to AWS | Leverege](https://www.leverege.com/blogpost/lessons-learned-migrating-from-gcp-to-aws)
- [How to approach a GCP-to-AWS migration](https://searchcloudcomputing.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-approach-a-GCP-to-AWS-migration)
- [How Rapyder helped ride-sharing app migrate from GCP to AWS | Rapyder](https://www.rapyder.com/case-studies/gcp-to-aws-case-study-ride-sharing-platform/)
- [Cloud Migration Use Case: Moving From AWS to GCP (PDF)](https://biqmind.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Biqmind-CloudMigration-UseCase-2020-04.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a detailed guide of steps you need to perform to migrate you k8s cluster from AWS to [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.8/how-to/migrate-aws-to-gcp/overview).

https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.8/how-to/migrate-aws-to-gcp/overview

https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.8/how-to/migrate-aws-to-gcp/aws-prerequisites

https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.8/how-to/migrate-aws-to-gcp/configure-aws-as-a-source

Comment: Threre are a bit outdated links. The latest versions are: 
* [Migrating individual VMs  |  Migrate for Compute Engine  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/5.0/how-to/migrating-vms)
* [Enabling Migrate for Compute Engine services  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/5.0/how-to/enable-services)
* [Installing the Migrate Connector  |  Migrate for Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/5.0/how-to/migrate-connector)